# Jenkins with spring issue

Tags: java, spring, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

We are using jenkins (2.60.1) version and it contains spring libraries of version 2.X.X.

Now, we are trying to build our jenkins plugin which internally uses Spring 4.0.2 RELEASE and uses AOP heavily.

The problem we are facing is that upon triggering the plugin, it reports an error saying :- **"AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator is only available on Java 1.5 and higher"**  , even though my version is 1.8.

Looks like it is using old spring libraries . How do we get around this problem and make jenkins use our spring libraries?
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: just provide the JAVA_HOME at the inject variable filed in BULD Configuration section.

Comment: HasnainAliBohra added and even confirmed that java 1.8 is being used. But still getting the same error. Looks like jenkins is using its own spring libraries which are 2.X.X version

Comment: No it is clearly saying that the compiled java libraries are 1.5 not 1.8.
Have you confirmed that JDK tab is pointing to correct version ?

Comment: HasnainAliBohra Yes.. i kind of debugged it and the java version was found to be 1.8. AOP 2.5 version doesn't support java > 1.5 . However, later version does. What i am seeing is that AOP 2.X.X version is present in jenkins.war file and plugin seems to use that instead of my spring libraries

Comment: The solution you suggested isn't working

Answer (score 0):

Have you confirmed that JDK tab is pointing to correct version ?
because it is still pointing to the java 1.5.

Comment: Yes.. i kind of debugged it and the java version was found to be 1.8. AOP 2.5 version doesn't support java > 1.5 . However, later version does. What i am seeing is that AOP 2.X.X version is present in jenkins.war file and plugin seems to use that instead of my spring libraries